# Does the async attribute represent a contract to not change the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

One of the reasons that browsers block parsing and rendering of a page when they find a `<script>` tag is to allow scripts to modify the DOM.

From [Load Non-blocking JavaScript with HTML5 Async and Defer](http://www.sitepoint.com/non-blocking-async-defer/):

> **The defer Attribute**
>
> The defer attribute makes a solemn promise to the browser. It states
>   that your JavaScript does not contain any document.write or DOM
>   modification nastiness:
>
> The browser will begin to
>   download file.js and other deferred scripts in parallel without
>   stopping page processing.defer was implemented in Internet Explorer
>   version 4.0 — over 12 years ago! It’s also been available in Firefox
>   since version 3.5.While all deferred scripts are guaranteed to run in
>   sequence, it’s difficult to determine when that will occur. In theory,
>   it should happen after the DOM has completely loaded, shortly before
>   the DOMContentLoaded event. In practice, it depends on the OS and
>   browser, whether the script is cached, and what other scripts are
>   doing at the time.

As I understand it, the `defer` attribute represents a 'contract' with the browser your script isn't going to change the DOM. Is the same also true of `async`?

(Of course, this doesn't prevent you loading scripts that change the DOM using `async` - you just have to structure your code so DOM-changing is done on document ready or load).

Comment: Take a look at the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer. It seems like the behaviour described in that article is totally diffrent from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not, and don't trust that article you linked to. The [`defer` and `async`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async) attributes tell the browser when the script should be executed and whether parsing should wait while loading it. It makes no promise.

So, using either of those attributes would *prevent* `document.write` from writing at the script's position, and, in the case of `defer`, *enables* straight DOM modification to affect DOM elements that are parsed after the `script` element.

Comment: OK, so maybe 'contract' was a bad choice of words - but if an async script is executed at an arbitrary point, you can't  be sure what is in the document so you should a least *avoid* DOM manipulation given the result is in effect undefined?

Comment: @KevinD You do know that anything *before* the script tag is parsed. You can still reliably do any DOM manipulation you could have done without the `async` attribute.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Thanks.